# Load Data From Linked Server to Another Linked Server

Tags: sql-server, linked-server

I have an Integration Server where I have defined linked servers of my sources (SQL Server database) and target database (Azure SQL DW). I have conditions where if the table does not exist I will use a `SELECT INTO`, then use an `INSERT INTO` when the table already exists.

My code is as follows:

```
SELECT * 
INTO [tgt_svr].[tgt_db].[tgt_sch].[tgt_tbl] 
FROM [tgt_svr].[tgt_db].[tgt_sch].[tgt_tbl];

INSERT INTO [tgt_svr].[tgt_db].[tgt_sch].[tgt_tbl] 
    SELECT * 
    FROM [tgt_svr].[tgt_db].[tgt_sch].[tgt_tbl];
```

However when I execute I get this error

> ... contains more than the maximum number of prefixes. The maximum is 2.

Appreciate any help how to resolve this and achieve my result to have this processing server extract from source server and load to target server.

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried [googling](https://www.google.pl/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=Q2DeV63tKeav8wegt6WgDw#q=contains+more+than+the+maximum+number+of+prefixes.+the+maximum+is+2) your issue?

Comment: Are you able to execute SELECT statement from target server?